# Array of generic classes

Tags: arrays, typescript, generics, types

I have an animal Hospital that has an array of Vets, each Vet specialises in a particular Animal.

```
interface Animal {}

class Dog implements Animal {}
class Cat implements Animal {}

class Vet<T extends Animal> {
  waitingList: T[];
}

class Hospital {
  vets: Vet[]
}
```

I am receiving an error with TypeScript 2.6 because Hospital.vets is missing it's generic type. Why is this? In theory each vet in the vets array might look after a different type of Animal. As a Hosptial all I know is that each Vet must meet the constraint .

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Animal%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Dog%20implements%20Animal%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Cat%20implements%20Animal%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Vet%3CT%20extends%20Animal%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20waitingList%3A%20T%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Hospital%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20vets%3A%20Vet%5B%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the generic parameter of the array item. You can use the base class `Animal`

```
interface Animal {}

class Dog implements Animal { }
class Cat implements Animal { }

class Vet<T extends Animal> {
    waitingList: T[];
}

class Hospital {
    vets: Vet<Animal>[] = [ new Vet<Dog>(), new Vet<Cat>() ]
}
```

Just a word of warning, depending on how you use this, it may let some errors slip through the type checker:

```
new Hospital().vets[0].waitingList.push(new Cat())
```

In the example above `new Hospital().vets[0]` is a `Vet<Dog>` but since we use `Vet<Animal>` we can also push a `Cat`, which may cause runtime errors.

Comment: okay, so I can just use the base class because I would be loosing any type information by putting them in an array anyway?

Comment: At runtime type information is lost anyway, at compile time, there are possible errors you are exposing yourself to that will not be caught by the checker, updated the answer with an example